# Automating Slapd Install

Tags: shell-script, ldap, debconf

I'm writing a script that automates the installation of slapd and phpldapadmin.

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
# make sure to run script as sudo 


# LDAP 

# update first 
apt-get -q -y update 

# install maven 

apt-get install -y maven 

# Install php dependencies 

apt-get -y install php php-cgi libapache2-mod-php php-common php-pear php-mbstring 

a2enconf php7.0-cgi 

service apache2 restart 

# Pre-seed the slapd passwords 

export DEBIAN_FRONTEND='non-interactive'

echo -e "slapd slapd/root_password password KappaRoss" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/root_password_again password KappaRoss" |debconf-set-selections

echo -e "slapd slapd/internal/adminpw password test" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/internal/generated_adminpw password test" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/password2 password test" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/password1 password test" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/domain string acu.local" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd shared/organization string IT410" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/backend string HDB" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/purge_database boolean true" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/move_old_database boolean true" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/allow_ldap_v2 boolean false" |debconf-set-selections
echo -e "slapd slapd/no_configuration boolean false" |debconf-set-selections

# Grab slapd and ldap-utils (pre-seeded)
apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils phpldapadmin

# Must reconfigure slapd for it to work properly 
sudo dpkg-reconfigure slapd 

# Gotta replace the ldap.conf file, it comments out stuff we need set by default - first open it for writing 

chmod 777 /etc/ldap/ldap.conf 

cat <<'EOF' > /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
#
# LDAP Defaults
#

# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.


BASE    dc=acu,dc=local
URI     ldap://104.219.54.109 ldap://104.219.54.109:666

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# TLS certificates (needed for GnuTLS)
TLS_CACERT      /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
EOF

# Be safe again 
chmod 744 /etc/ldap/ldap.conf 


# Now change all values in /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php to their actual values from example, or .com or localhost (I use sed)


# Line 286 
sed -i "s@$servers->setValue('server','name','My LDAP Server');.*@$servers->setValue('server','name','Nathans_LDAP');@" /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
# Line 293 
sed -i "s@$servers->setValue('server','host','127.0.0.1');.*@$servers->setValue('server','host','104.219.54.109');@" /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php 
# Line 300 
sed -i "s@$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=example,dc=com'));.*@$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=acu,dc=local'));@" /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php
# Line 326 
sed -i "s@$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com');.*@$servers->setValue('login','bind_id','cn=admin,dc=acu,dc=local');@" /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php

# Prevent error when creating users 

sed -i "s@$default = $this->getServer()->getValue('appearance','password_hash');.*@$default = $this->getServer()->getValue('appearance','password_hash_custom');@g" /usr/share/phpldapadmin/lib/TemplateRender.php

service apache2 restart 

echo ------------------------# 
echo 'PHPldapadmin installed.'
echo ------------------------# 

echo ""

echo ------------------------------------------------------------# 
echo 'Can now access phpldapadmin at http://your-ip/phpldapadmin.'
echo ------------------------------------------------------------# 

echo ""

echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------#
echo 'Username should be acu.local, password is the adminpw set during setup.'
echo ------------------------------------------------------------------------# S

# Logging 

echo -e 'Maven installed -done by' $USER 'at time\n' $DATE '\n' >> /var/log/installs/log.txt
echo -e 'slapd and ldap-utils configured and installed -done by' $USER 'at time\n' $DATE '\n' >> /var/log/installs/log.txt
echo -e 'phpldapadmin install configured -done by' $USER 'at time\n' $DATE '\n' >> /var/log/installs/log.txt
echo -e 'LDAP installed completed by' $USER 'at time\n' $DATE '\n' >> /var/log/installs/log.txt
```

Everything runs great, except I think that the debconf set selections for pre-seeding the "dpkg-reconfigure slapd" portion aren't being fully applied. 
Specifically, when I try to log into phpldapadmin with the admin password I pre-seed, it fails. I have to run "dpkg-reconfigure slapd" again (manually this time) in the terminal and set another admin password, then I can log into phpldapadmin properly and everything works. Any help is appreciated, I need this application fully automated for my final and I'm really close as is.

Answer (score 4):

my debconf preseed looks a bit different, but it is for `stretch`:

```
cat > /root/debconf-slapd.conf << 'EOF'
slapd slapd/password1 password admin
slapd slapd/internal/adminpw password admin
slapd slapd/internal/generated_adminpw password admin
slapd slapd/password2 password admin
slapd slapd/unsafe_selfwrite_acl note
slapd slapd/purge_database boolean false
slapd slapd/domain string phys.ethz.ch
slapd slapd/ppolicy_schema_needs_update select abort installation
slapd slapd/invalid_config boolean true
slapd slapd/move_old_database boolean false
slapd slapd/backend select MDB
slapd shared/organization string ETH Zurich
slapd slapd/dump_database_destdir string /var/backups/slapd-VERSION
slapd slapd/no_configuration boolean false
slapd slapd/dump_database select when needed
slapd slapd/password_mismatch note
EOF
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
cat /root/debconf-slapd.conf | debconf-set-selections
apt install ldap-utils slapd -y
```

after that I use `ldapmodify` to update the password immediately. this is done by storing the hash in ldap, so the plain text password is not shown in the script:

```
cat > /root/admin_pw_config_dit.ldif << 'EOF'
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {CRYPT}<sha-512_hash_here>
EOF
cat > /root/admin_pw_normal_dit.ldif << 'EOF'
dn: cn=admin,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: {CRYPT}<sha-512_hash_here>
ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -x -D cn=admin,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch -w admin -f /root/admin_pw_normal_dit.ldif
ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -f /root/admin_pw_config_dit.ldif
# verify
ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -x -D cn=admin,dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch -W -b dc=phys,dc=ethz,dc=ch cn=admin | grep 'userPassword'
```

replace `<sha-512_hash_here>` with the hash value of your password.

you can generate such hashes by using this script: https://github.com/rda0/mkpw

alternatively, one could also use `slappasswd -h <hashing-algorithm> -s <new_password>`

Comment: ...for the password and password hash, you can use the "slappasswd" command. YMMV, maybe not all distros have it available. Might not work if you were to compile it. Maybe there is, maybe it will.